# how to reduce this string manipulation code

Tags: php, string

I have written below code which little complex. Is it any modification possible to **reduce below code within less step instead of cascading it**.

```
$countries='IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';      //list country codes separated by comma
$countries=explode(',',$countries);     //partition from ,
$countries=implode('\',\'',$countries);     //add ' at start and end of the country code
$countries="'".$countries."'";              //add ' to first and last country code
$countries=explode(',',$countries);         //create array by breaking it from ,
print_r($countries);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array ( [0] => 'IN' [1] => 'US' [2] => 'AU' [3] => 'MY' [4] => 'TH' [5]
>   => 'KR' [6] => 'TW' )

Comment: So you want a final array, that is from your initial string, but with `' '` around the values?

Comment: Maybe a preg_replace could do it

Comment: in your loop where u print value add " '$value' " like this

Comment: something like - `$countries = "'".str_replace(",", "','", $countries)."'";
$countries=explode(',',$countries); `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1, $2... $n` in regular expression replaces are references to the matches wrapped in parenthesis. `$0` would be the entire match, `$1` would be the first parenthesized capture, `$2` would be the second, etc.

```
$1 is a reference to whatever is matched by the first (.*)
$2 is a reference to (\?|&)
$4 is a reference to the second (.*)
```

---

```
$countries = 'IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';
$countries = explode(',',preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2})/', "'$1'", $countries));
print_r($countries);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array ( [0] => 'IN' [1] => 'US' [2] => 'AU' [3] => 'MY' [4] => 'TH'
>   [5] => 'KR' [6] => 'TW' )

ref : http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

For output like below:

> Array ( [0] => 'IN' [1] => 'US' [2] => 'AU' [3] => 'MY' [4] => 'TH' [5] => 'KR' [6] => 'TW' )

You can do like below:

```
$countries='IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';      //list country codes separated by comma
$countries= explode(',',$countries);     //partition from ,
$countries= "'".implode("','",$countries)."'";    

$countries=explode(',',$countries);         //create array by breaking it from ,
print_r($countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Like

```
$countries='IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';     
$countries=explode(',',$countries);    
$countries2 = array_map(function($val) { return "'".$val."'";} , $countries);
print_r($countries2);
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array ( [0] => 'IN' [1] => 'US' [2] => 'AU' [3] => 'MY' [4] => 'TH' [5] => 'KR' [6] => 'TW' )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $countries='IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';
 $countries = preg_replace("/(\b)/", "'$1", $countries);
 $countries = explode(",", $countries);
 Var_dump($countries);
 ?>
```

Link to working example:
Remember to change to preg_replace
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ff7

Comment: what does "'$1'" do?

Comment: That tells preg_replace to add a ' before the search match. The match is called $1 in preg_replace

Comment: @kpatil WOW! Two days later and my answer is still not correct or even thanked? And you accepted Rohans answer which is more or less a copy of mine and posted AFTER MY ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like:

```
$countries = 'IN,US,AU,MY,TH,KR,TW';
$countries = preg_replace('/([A-z]{2})/', "'$1'", $countries);
$countries = explode(',',$countries);
```

Comment: what does  "'$1'" do?

Comment: $1 mean the match between the () in the regular expression, if you have an regex with more then one () you can use $1 for first match between the (), the $2 second one, the numbers can be from $0 to $99. You can finde it for the preg_replace in http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php